# Android: Error inflating class - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android

I try to implement EasyRTC on my Android application but i got some problem. I used [This custom view][1] instead of WebView to support chrome. I just follow their guide and build it in Android phone (API 17) that a got some problem:

```
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.VideoCallActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class us.costan.chrome.ChromeView
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class us.costan.chrome.ChromeView
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at com.example.myapp.VideoCallActivity.onCreate(VideoCallActivity.java:15)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    ... 11 more
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    ... 22 more
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.nativeInit:(Lorg/chromium/android_webview/AwWebContentsDelegate;Lorg/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClientBridge;)I
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.nativeInit(Native Method)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:363)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:323)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    at us.costan.chrome.ChromeView.<init>(ChromeView.java:91)
12-25 11:12:01.800: E/AndroidRuntime(16111):    ... 25 more
```

xml file:

```xml
<us.costan.chrome.ChromeView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</us.costan.chrome.ChromeView>
```

in VideoCallActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_call);
    ChromeView chromeView = (ChromeView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    chromeView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    chromeView.loadUrl(testURL);
}
```

And this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ChromeView.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First to first.You getting your Very First error on line 35.Go to eclipse go to left panel,right click and hit SHOW LINES and see what is written inside your code on line 35.Thats the main problem.It might be some missmatch code.Another problem is that your gettin this error in your OnCreate method i believe or even more early than reaching onCreate.Check there for your code.But mainly i thing you shouldn pass initialize to chromeview but declare it fully in your mainactivity like for example OpenGlS does when its extendin rendering class where its drawn(google for examples).Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh i think i found your problem.Your using custom view inside xml so it means YOU HAVE TO DECLARE AND FINDVIEW OF THAT CUSTOM VIEW inside your activity like this `us.costan.chrome.ChromeView chrome;
chrome = (us.costan.chrome.ChromeView)findViewById(R.id.webView)
setContentView(chrome)`